# How put numered marker with geojson on leaflet

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson, markers

Forget everything until here, I spent the dawn trying, to see if I could move forward, I'll explain. I have a map and I need to enumerate the 1 to 15 markings. The markings are correct, the problem that marks only 1, 15 times. This is my json:

https://github.com/eltonsantos/analise_integrada/blob/master/path.js

simple json, nothing much

My code is:

```
var rotas = L.geoJSON(paradas, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){
        console.log("Qtd: " + paradas.features.length)
        for(var i = 1; i <= paradas.features.length; i++){
            return L.marker(latlng, {
                icon: new L.AwesomeNumberMarkers({
                    number: i,
                    markerColor: 'purple'
                })
            })
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

This code does not show any error message, it just shows all my points being numbered all with 1. I just wanted them to be numbered from 1 to 15, according to the amount in json

Comment: You said you can enumerate when you don't use geoGSON. Would you be able to show an example of the code where your enumeration works? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I need exactly this: https://github.com/Zahidul-Islam/Leaflet.awesome-numbered-marker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pointToLayer` function option is called *once per marker* (per `"Point"` type feature to be exact). You have a *single* `latlng` value per function call.

Therefore you will understand that it is pointless trying to loop up to your `paradas.features.length`.

Furthermore, your loop `return`s at its first iteration, that is why you see only icons with "1" enumeration.

Since you want the `L.geoJSON` factory to increment your enumeration each time it calls your `pointToLayer` function, you just need to hold the counter in an outer scope:

```js
var map = L.map('map');

// Hold the counter in an outer scope.
var i = 0;

var rotas = L.geoJSON(paradas, {
  //onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    console.log("Qtd: " + paradas.features.length)
    // Increment the counter.
    i += 1;
    // No need to loop.
    //for (var i = 1; i <= paradas.features.length; i++) {
      // Directly return the Marker for the given `latlng`
      return L.marker(latlng, {
        icon: new L.AwesomeNumberMarkers({
          number: i,
          markerColor: 'purple',
        }),
      });
    //}
  }
}).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(rotas.getBounds());

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<!-- Leaflet assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<!-- Leaflet.AwesomeNumberMarkers assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/Zahidul-Islam/Leaflet.awesome-numbered-marker/f7b5b594e9fc451cd006ee345220a86390eb1cf1/src/leaflet_awesome_number_markers.css" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Zahidul-Islam/Leaflet.awesome-numbered-marker/f7b5b594e9fc451cd006ee345220a86390eb1cf1/src/leaflet_awesome_number_markers.js"></script>

<!-- your GeoJSON data that defines the `paradas` global variable -->
<script src="https://rawgit.com/eltonsantos/analise_integrada/8b771bed3bd0bbfe1da3d02ce09b37630a637a0c/path.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 180px"></div>
```