# Javascript pass results of function into another function in a Leaflet.js project

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, leaflet, closures

I'm working on a project using Leaflet.js and geoJson data. I'm making a choropleth map and I am trying to pass the results of one function into another function. I don't think this scenario is unique to Leaflet and I think I'm just stumbling when it comes to passing results of one function as the parameter of another function.

I have a function that styles the countries in the map based on their GDP values pulled from an API:

```
 function getColor(d) {
      return d > 1000000 ? '#005824' :
          d > 500000  ? '#238b45' :
          d > 200000  ? '#41ae76' :
          d > 100000  ? '#66c2a4' :
          d > 50000   ? '#99d8c9' :
          d > 20000   ? '#ccece6' :
          d > 15000   ? '#edf8fb':
                       '#fff'
    }
```

This function is called by this second function:

```
  function style(feature) {
      return {
          fillColor: getColor(100000),
          weight: 2,
          opacity: 1,
          color: 'white',
          //dashArray: '3',
          fillOpacity: 0.7,
          stroke: true,
          weight: .5,
          fill: true,
          clickable: true
      };
    }
```

As you can see I currently have 100000 hardcoded as the getColor function's parameter. I would like to change this so that the data from the API is passed to getColor rather than this hardcoded value.

I have GDP data being pulled from an API and  I am able to console.log it with this function:

```
function getGDP(gdp) {
      for(var i = 0; i < countriesData.features.length; i++) {
       console.log(countriesData.features[i].properties.name + ' ' + countriesData.features[i].properties.gdp_md_est);
       return countriesData.features[i].properties.gdp_md_est;
      }
    }
```

How do I pass the resultes of the getGDP() function the to getColor() function inside of the style() function?

Does this have to involve closures? If so, how do I use a closure for this? I don't believe this issue is exclusive to Leaflet or this project, I think I am just having trouble wrapping my head around how to pass the returned value of one function to another function that is nested within a third function.

The getColor function has to iterate over the **countriesData.features[i].properties.gdp_md_est** element.

Would something like this work:

```
function style(feature) {
      return {
          //fillColor: getColor(100000),
          fillColor: getColor(function(d) {
            for(var i = 0; i < countriesData.features.length; i++) {
             var data =  countriesData.features[i].properties.gdp_md_est;
             return data;
            }
          }),
          weight: 2,
          opacity: 1,
          color: 'white',
          //dashArray: '3',
          fillOpacity: 0.7,
          stroke: true,
          weight: .5,
          fill: true,
          clickable: true
      };
    }
```

Comment: `getColor(getGDP(???))` - as you haven't shown how you call getGDP, not sure what `???` should be ... probably wrong as you state `iterate over` ... and haven't shown how `.gdp_md_est` even relates to `100000`

Comment: What a better way of doing this be to pass a callback function to getColor inside of the style function?

Comment: I want to get rid of the hardcoded 100000 value and pass getColor the iterated data from the API/getGDP

Comment: Firstly, you are not iterating in getGDP - the return is ensuring you always return `countriesData.features[0].properties.gdp_md_est` - note the `0` instead of the `i`. Also, I think there's an important "link" between `fillColor` and whatever you want `getGDP` to return that you are not showing. You know what you want, but you haven't explained it at all

Comment: I have JSON data with gdp data in it. I want to color various countries depending on the data value. I want getColor() inside of style() to iterate through every country's gdp and color it appropriately.

Comment: you keep using the word `iterate`, yet your for loop doesn't, because of the return - and you want `getColor....` to return multiple values at once? that's what I'm reading ... fillColor can only be a single value

Comment: I understand the getGDP function had an error in it and the return function was terminating the for loop. I want fillColor to display different colors for each country based on the GDP value from the JSON.

Comment: is that what the `gdp` argument was supposed to help with? It's still very unclear to me what you want

Comment: I have JSON data with GDP data in it. I have data for 30-something different countries. I want to grab the data for each country and color each country on the map according to the value of the GDP. countriesData.features[5].properties.gdp_md_est grabs the color for the 5th element, in this case Albania, it colors Albania accordingly. countriesData.features[0].properties.gdp_md_est grabs the data for the 0th country in the data, Austria, and colors it accordingly. I want fillColor to go through each element and color each country the way it should according to the value.

Comment: fillColor needs to be a single value, it can not iterate, it is a style property

Answer (score 0):

Similarly as in this other [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708899/how-put-numered-marker-with-geojson-on-leaflet) and as shown in the [Leaflet choropleth map tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) (section "Adding Some Colors"), you just have to realize that the Leaflet [`L.geoJSON`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#geojson) factory will loop through the Features data you pass it, and call your [`style`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#geojson-style) function *once per Feature*, with that single Feature data as argument to your `style` function, as the code in your question is already setup.

Since you surely want to call your `getColor` function with data associated to that single Feature (so that the latter is styled according to its data and not according to data from all other Features), you understand that it is counterproductive trying to loop through *all* your Features with your `getGDP` function and trying to use all that data in your `style` function.

```js
function style(feature) {
  return {
    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.gdp_md_est),
    // etc.
  };
}
```